# Java method called from another thread, data update is not instantaneous

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to use a separate thread to go through a nested for cycle (to avoid frozen UI, and make things simpler) in Java:

```
public class scan2D extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        float data;
        for (int y = 0; y<GUI.max_y; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x<GUI.max_x; x++) {
                GUI.model.set(GUI.edaq.getdata());
            } 
        }
        GUI.model.save();
    }
}
```

scan2d object is created in the GUI object, and is started by pressing a start button of GUI. Everything works, except the "model" object is updated only once, in the end by all the data, instead one-by-one. I would like to have it updated as soon as data is read from "edaq" and sent to model. Model is observed by a view. How can I make the update instantaneous?

**Update**
Thank you for all your helping advice and comments! Sorry I didn't include all the code which apparently contribute to the problem. I'm a beginner. I made a simplified, minimal "working" example, which also shows the symptom:

```
package test;

public class GUI {
    static Model model;
    static scan2D scan2d;
    public GUI() {
        model = new Model();
        scan2d = new scan2D();
        scan2d.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
}

class Model {
    public void set(int data)
    {
        System.out.print(data);
    }
}

public class scan2D extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        int data;
        for (int y = 0; y<=10; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x<=10; x++) {
                try {Thread.sleep(100);}
                catch(InterruptedException ex){}
                GUI.model.set(x+y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try it with 100ms delay, I get all the data shown at the end in the netbeans output window, simultaneously. When I use 1000s, it works, data gets displayed one-by-one on the output. Is it just a display issue?

Comment: And i guess that you are starting new thread everytime data is modified... ?

Comment: How do you run that thread? If you use `run()` it does not start a new thread. If you use `start()` you'd better be sure that the model and then GUI representing it is thread safe.

Comment: How do you know the model is only updated once?

Comment: Are you using Swing, SWT or some other toolkit? Your UI toolkit probably requires that updates to the GUI be done from the GUI thread. You can get unexpected results if you update the GUI from other threads.

Comment: I guess you have to move `GUI.model.save();` in the loop after `GUI.model.set(...)`, that call probably fires model changed event.

Comment: Have you tried adding Thread.yield() after GUI.model.set(GUI.edaq.getdata()); ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should start new thread (aka execute your `run` method) everytime your data changes. I can only guess that you are starting new thread only once, after all changes to model are made. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

How is your GUI observing changes in the model? I assume you have to notify the guy to perform the update. This notification has to be performed on the event dispatch thread.

Everything that affects the gui must happen on the gui's thread - e.g. via

```
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // update guy
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I thought you were talking about a swing GUI. A console is not very graphical. I assume the console has a buffer which is flushed only from time to time...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your model sends notification only at `GUI.model.save();`. So you should call `GUI.model.save()`; after every time you change the model:

```
public class scan2D extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        float data;
        for (int y = 0; y<GUI.max_y; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x<GUI.max_x; x++) {
                GUI.model.set(GUI.edaq.getdata());
                GUI.model.save();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. Your GUI is just a console?!? I guess your writes to the console are cached and flushed only every x milliseconds ...